# Eigenvalues calculated using Qutip breaks for specific values of coupling constant

Tags: python, qutip

I am trying to create a plot of Eigenenergies vs coupling constant g for my Jaynes-Cummings (JC) hamiltonian. I have noticed that when I try this, the eigenenergies seem to "break" at points where I would expect there to be crossings between eigenenergies. I am new to Qutip, so this could very well be an error in my code, however I have not been able to spot it. Is there a way to fix this issue?

Here is a portion of my code:

```
def JC(N, g, omega, delta):

    sz = tensor(qeye(N), sigmaz())
    a = tensor(destroy(N), qeye(2))

    sp = tensor(qeye(N), sigmap())
    sm = tensor(qeye(N), sigmam())

    H = omega*a.dag()*a + 0.5*(delta + omega)*sz + g*(a*sp + a.dag()*sm)

    EigVal, EigVec = H.eigenstates()

    return EigVal
```

When I plot the i'th eigenenergies vs g (for omega = 1 and detuning = 0), I get

[image: i'th eigenenergies vs g, for i = [0, 6]]

I have tried different ways of writing the operators, and tried using a different technique to calculate the eigenvalues of the hamiltonian but other problems arose. I have calculated this analytically and I expect a similar plot however without the zigzag features.

Comment: Those eigen-energies look correct -- I expect this is an issue with how the graph is being colored. Eigenvectors are calculated using numpy and don't necessarily guarantee order, I suspect you'll need to figure out which eigenvector each value is associated with and assign your energies to their correct groups. Right now it looks like they're coming out in numerical order, and the color of the plot is changing accordingly. In essence -- when you have an avoided crossing, I suspect what is actually happening is we're falling victim to sorting.

Comment: @A10, I think that you make a very good point and I most likely agree that sorting is the issue. I have been trying to code this for the last day but I have been having many difficulties. Do you happen to have any recommendations on good techniques for sorting this type of problem?

Comment: @A10 I was able to make a sorting algorithm for the values, however, that does not seem to have fixed the issue, in fact, it still produces the same plot.

Comment: You'll need to sort them according to their Eigenvectors. Each energy band you have (if I remember my cavity optics still..) represents something like |s, N>, where s is your 0/1 state, and N is the number of photons in your cavity (again, if I remember correctly). You'll need to get the associated eigenvectors for each eigenvalue for each g, and place them in the correct category accordingly. Remember that your JC model is block diagonal, so your eigenvectors should simplify to something like [0,1], [1,0] for each number of photons.

Comment: Alternatively, you could just color every line black and label them with annotations!

Comment: You may find [this document](https://www.scribd.com/document/699301617/Jaynes-Cumming-model-and-descendants) helpful for what you're observing in these band structures. It goes in pretty deep and uses the language of the brillouin structure of the energy bands you're observing. With any luck it should give you a bit more of an intuitive understanding of what you're observing, and how you may consider coloring (or in fact _not_ coloring) your resulting spectra.

Comment: @A10, Thank you, it seems to have worked. I noticed that I had made a small mistake in my code when I was sorting the eigenvectors. Thank you as well for the very helpful document that you shared.